# jQuery UI Dialog - close after X seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, settimeout

This code works perfectly, except - dialog window will not close after X miliseconds as i expect...

`setTimeout` function is executed (i put alert() there and it worked...), so i assume problem is with `$("#alert div").dialog('close');` but i do not know what is wrong...

```
if ($("#alert").length) {
    var title;
    if ($("#alert span").length) {
        title = $("#alert span").text();
    }
    $("#alert div").dialog({
        title: title,
        modal: true,
        open: function() {
            setTimeout(function() {
                $("#alert div").dialog('close');
            }, 2000);
        }
    });
}
```

EDIT:
If it helps, here is HTML:

```
<div id="alert">
    <span>Password change</span>
    <div>Password was successfully changed.</div>
</div>
```

**RESOLVED!** Would be great if anyone has idea, why my code does not work...

Comment: See my updated answer with an explanation as to why what you would expect to work doesn't.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have a scoping issue. Try this **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/246LG/)**:

```
if ($("#alert").length) {
    var title;
    if ($("#alert span").length) {
        title = $("#alert span").text();
    }
    $("#alert div").dialog({
        title: title,
        modal: true,
        open: function() {
            var foo = $(this);
            setTimeout(function() {
               foo.dialog('close');
            }, 2000);
        }
    });
}​
```

The reason this is happening, and not working like you might expect, is due to the way you reference the target div that becomes the dialog, and the way that jQuery UI builds the dialog. If you check out a developer console you'll see that jQuery pulls your div out of it's original position in the DOM and therefor no longer can be referenced to by `#alert div` since it's no longer a child of `#alert`. If you had given that div its own ID, it would work as expected and you wouldn't need the temporary variable to refer to it.

Comment: Why is scoping an issue here? It's not like he's trying to use `this` inside the setTimeout callback

Comment: @Codemonkey - see my update for the reason. Let me know if you need more detail.

Comment: So basicly, jQuery UI is not that smart to work with "#alert div" as well as with "#alert"...

Comment: Well I wouldn't say that. What the issue is is that jQuery does some shuffling of elements behind the scenes and while your original reference is fine to make the dialog, it doesn't hold true to close it two seconds later because jQuery has already made changes.

Answer (score 0):

**Tested and working live demo:**

http://jsfiddle.net/oscarj24/q6tD9/2/

I think this way is better:

```
jQuery.fn.exists = function(){return this.length>0;}

$(function() {
    if($('#alert').exists()){
        var modal = $('#alert div');
        modal.dialog({ title: $('#alert span').text(), modal: true });
        var opened = modal.dialog('isOpen');
        if(opened){
            setTimeout(function(){ 
               modal.dialog('close'); 
            }, 2000);
        }
    }
});​
```